# Creating a factory to pass data from directive to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that returns an array for each element of an ng-repeat list after an $http call is made.

Looks like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp');


app.directive('release', ['musicInfoService', 'dataService',
  function(musicInfoService, dataService) {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        release: '=',
        artist: '='
      },
      template: '<div class="release">' +
        '<div class="wrapper"><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{imageSrc}}"/><div id="text" ng-click="getVersions(release)"></div></div>{{release.title | characters:45}}' +
        '<ul><li ng-repeat="version in defaultFormat">{{version.format}}</li><li ng-show="basicFormat">{{basicFormat}}</li></ul>'+
        '</div>',
      replace: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var defaultImage = 'img/record-default.png';
        scope.imageSrc = defaultImage;
        musicInfoService.getAlbumInfo(scope.artist.name, scope.release.title)
          .success(function(data) {
            if (data.error) return;

            var image = data.album.image[2],
              imageUrl = defaultImage;

            if (image['#text'] !== '') {
              imageUrl = image['#text'];
            }

            scope.imageSrc = imageUrl;
          });
        var defaultFormat = scope.release.format;
        musicInfoService.getReleaseVersions(scope.release.id)
        .success(function(data) {
            if (data.error) return;

            var format = data.versions,
              formats = scope.release.format;

            if (format !== '') {
              formats = format;
            }

            scope.defaultFormat = formats;
            dataService.setItems(scope.defaultFormat);
          })
          .error(function($scope) {
            scope.basicFormat = scope.release.format;
            dataService.setItems(scope.basicFormat);
         });
      }
    };
  }
]);

app.factory('dataService', [function($scope){
   var _items= "";
   return { 
          setItems:function(value){
             _items=value;
          },
          getItems:function(){
             return _items;
          }
  };
}]);
```

Now, I need to be able to pass this data to a div (outside the directive), when an element is clicked.

```
<div class="infinite" infinite-scroll="loadDetails()">
      <div ng-repeat="row in main.rows">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3" ng-repeat="release in row | filter:main.album" ng-click="main.releaseClicked=release;" ng-class="{'selected':main.releaseClicked==release}">
            <release release="release" artist="main.artist"></release> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="release in row" ng-if="main.releaseClicked==release">
          <div id="collapse" ng-controller="VersionController" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="inner">
              <ul>
                <li>{{release.title}}</li>
                <li ng-repeat="version in versions">
                  {{version.format}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So on ng-click="main.releaseClicked=release;, the second row is displayed, and the ng-repeat should be populated with the data coming from VersionController.

I've learned in another question that I should set the data in a variable once it comes down from the server, and get it once the function VersionController is called (as it will be different data for each element clicked on), but so far I couldn't get to do it.

I've tried like so, but **I'm getting the results from the last item displayed** in every single item, which means the data from the last element is stored, but **the variable is not updated** on click to each item:

Right after my directive:

```
app.factory('dataService', [function($scope){
   var _items= "";
   return { 
          setItems:function(value){
             _items=value;
          },
          getItems:function(){
             return _items;
          }
  };
}]);
```

And then at the end of script.js

```
function VersionController($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.versions = dataService.getItems();
  console.log($scope.versions);
}
```

Here's the full file:

```
    (function(){

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'truncate']);

var Ctrl = function(musicInfoService) {
  this.musicInfoService = musicInfoService;
};

Ctrl.prototype.onArtistChange = function(){
  var artist = this.artist;

  if(angular.isUndefined(artist)) return;

  var pos = artist.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(', the');

  if (pos != -1) {
    artist.name = 'The ' + artist.name.slice(0, pos);
  }
};

Ctrl.prototype.reset = function(){
  this.sliding = false;
  this.name = undefined;
};

Ctrl.prototype.search = function(name) {
  var _this = this;

  if (name) {
    _this.musicInfoService.searchArtists(name)
    .success(function(data) {
      _this.clicked = false;
      _this.results = data.results;
    });
  }
};

Ctrl.prototype.getDetails = function(id) {
  var _this = this;

  _this.musicInfoService.getDetails(id)
  .then(function(data){
    _this.artist = data.artist;
    _this.releases = data.releases;
    _this.onArtistChange();

   _this.getRows = function(array) {
    var rows = [];
    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 4;
    for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = array.slice(i,i+chunk);

        rows.push(temparray);
    }
    return rows;
    };
    _this.rows = _this.getRows(data.releases);
  });

  _this.clicked = true;
  _this.sliding = true;
};

Ctrl.$inject = ['musicInfoService'];

app.controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);



}());

function VersionController($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.versions = dataService.getItems();
  console.log($scope.versions);
}
```

Also, in the directive I'm injecting the dataService, so the problem shouldn't come from there.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**: Here's [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBdvtN6ayo59017rLKPs?p=preview). Notice than in the example, the release versions appear under the release title, but what I'm aiming to do is to show them only when the release item is clicked (in the box under).

Comment: Can you post all of your code? What's the name of your directive? I'm not seeing where you are actually using your directive in your view...and also, did you mean controller by any chance? I'm trying to understand the architecture you've built here.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 - updated! Added a Plunker also.

Comment: Nice app, loving the UI! That said, your code is a little strange in terms of Angular conventions. Is there any reason that you're calling your `dataService` and `musicInfoService` in your directive, instead of in your controller? The issue is that you want to separate your data from your content, but you've coupled them together. You could use a `$scope` variable in your controller to hold the data.

Comment: I had a complete different version of the code made by me (with the help of loads of S.O. users, as I'm currently learning Angular), and one of the users refactored it completely, so I'm not so sure what to answer to your question as I'm still trying to figure out the code myself... On the other hand, thanks for the compliments! Has no pretension whatsoever, outside learning how to build stuff with Angular : )

Comment: Angular's a fun framework, definitely, glad you're having fun! That said, the way you're using prototypical inheritance manually in your scope (and the way you're calling your view) seems pretty unconventional, and even unnecessary. I'll post a refactor and try to explain my steps with the help of some documentation.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 that would be fantastic, for real. Send u a hug from Berlin.